# Center text at a given point on a WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, f#

I have a `Controls.Canvas` with several shapes on it and would like to add textual labels that are centered on given points (I'm drawing a tree with labelled vertices). What is the simplest way to do this programmatically in WPF?

I have tried setting `RenderTransform` and calling `Controls.Canvas.SetLeft` etc. but neither position the label where I want it. WPF seems to support positioning only at given left, right, top and bottom coordinates and not centered on a given coordinate and the `Width` property is `NaN` and the `ActualWidth` property is `0.0` when I construct the `Canvas`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could achieve this by binding the margin of the label to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the label, and multiplying these values with -0.5. This moves the label left by half its width; and it moves the label upwards by half its height.

Here is an example:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CenteredLabelTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CenteredLabelTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CenterConverter x:Key="centerConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="40" TextAlignment="Center" Text="MMMMMM">
            <TextBlock.Margin>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource centerConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="txt" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="txt" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Margin>
        </TextBlock>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="39" Width="2" Height="2" Fill="Red"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

The red rectangle highlights the coordinate (40, 40) on which the label "MMMMMM" is centered.

Converter:

```
public class CenterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        double width = (double) values[0];
        double height = (double)values[1];

        return new Thickness(-width/2, -height/2, 0, 0);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: centered label]

In order to do that programmatically, define an attached property `Mover.MoveToMiddle`, like this:

```
public class Mover : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MoveToMiddleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MoveToMiddle", typeof (bool), typeof (Mover),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, PropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetMoveToMiddle(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MoveToMiddleProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetMoveToMiddle(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(MoveToMiddleProperty);
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
            multiBinding.Converter = new CenterConverter();
            multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ActualWidth") {Source = element});
            multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ActualHeight") {Source = element});
            element.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, multiBinding);
        }
        else
        {
            element.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty);
        }
    }

}
```

Setting `Mover.MoveToMiddle` to `true` means that the margin of that framework element is automatically bound to its actual width and height such that the framework element is moved to its center point.

You would use it in your XAML code like this:

```
<Window x:Class="CenteredLabelTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CenteredLabelTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CenterConverter x:Key="centerConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="40" TextAlignment="Center" Text="MMMMMM"
              local:Mover.MoveToMiddle="True"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="39" Width="2" Height="2" Fill="Red"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

An alternative would be to bind to `RenderTransform` instead of `Margin`. In this case, the converter would return

```
return new TranslateTransform(-width / 2, -height / 2);
```

and the attached property's callback method would contain these lines:

```
if ((bool)e.NewValue)
{
    ...
    element.SetBinding(UIElement.RenderTransformProperty, multiBinding);
}
else
{
    element.ClearValue(UIElement.RenderTransformProperty);
}
```

This alternative has the advantage that the effect of the attached property is visible in the Visual Studio designer (which is not the case when setting the Margin property).

Answer (score 12):

This also works, with less binding.

```
public class CenterOnPoint
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterPointProperty =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CenterPoint", typeof (Point), typeof (CenterOnPoint),
     new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnPointChanged));

  public static void SetCenterPoint(UIElement element, Point value)
  {
     element.SetValue(CenterPointProperty, value);
  }

  public static Point GetCenterPoint(UIElement element)
  {
     return (Point) element.GetValue(CenterPointProperty);
  }

  private static void OnPointChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     var element = (FrameworkElement)d;
     element.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
     element.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
     var newPoint = (Point)e.NewValue;
     element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newPoint.X - (element.ActualWidth / 2));
     element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newPoint.Y - (element.ActualHeight / 2));
  }

  private static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     var element = (FrameworkElement) sender;
     var newPoint = GetCenterPoint(element);
     element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newPoint.X - (e.NewSize.Width / 2));
     element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newPoint.Y - (e.NewSize.Height / 2));
  }
}
```

And you use it like this...

```
label.SetValue(CenterOnPoint.CenterPointProperty, new Point(100, 100));
```

Comment: People might look at these answers and think that it's too complicated for the simple requirements of the question, but this isn't just showing you how to centre a label. This code is defining a behaviour that will centre any `FrameworkElement` on a point and keep it centred, even when that element's size might be changing.

Comment: This works really well.  From XAML the usage is:
    <TextBlock Text="Text" CenterOnPoint.CenterPoint="100,100" />
Notice the automatic conversion of "100,100" to Point.

Comment: Works perfectly, even with non WPF XAML e.g. Windows 10 universal, Thanks!

Comment: This solution is also easily adaptable for other purposes, for example you could do a "RightAlign" without too much modification.

Comment: Addition to this which handle's the case where the item is not visible when the point value changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71847286/3195477

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Jon, I didn't understand your question all the way yesterday on Twitter.
Here's how I might try it in F#!  @cammcad

#r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
    Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFramework.dll"
    #r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase.dll"
    #r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationCore.dll"

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Shapes
open System.Windows.Media
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Markup
open System.Xml

(* Add shape and label to canvas at specific location *)
let addShapeAndLabel_at_coordinate (label: string) (coordinate: float * float) (c:    Canvas) = 
  let btn = Button(Content=label,Foreground=SolidColorBrush(Colors.White))
  let template = 
     "<ControlTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
        TargetType=\"Button\">" +
        "<Grid>" +
        " <Ellipse Width=\"15\" Height=\"15\" Fill=\"Orange\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\"/>" +
        " <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\" " + "VerticalAlignment=\"Center\"/> " + 
        "</Grid>" +
        "</ControlTemplate>"

  btn.Template <- XamlReader.Parse(template) :?> ControlTemplate
  c.Children.Add(btn) |> ignore
  let textsize =  
       FormattedText(label,CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("enus"),
       FlowDirection.LeftToRight,Typeface("Verdana"),32.0,Brushes.White)
       |> fun x -> x.MinWidth, x.LineHeight
  let left,top = coordinate
  let middle_point_width = fst(textsize) / 2.0
  let middle_point_height = snd(textsize) / 2.0
  Canvas.SetLeft(btn,left - middle_point_width)
  Canvas.SetTop(btn,top - middle_point_height)

let shell = new Window(Width=300.0,Height=300.0)
let canvas = new   Canvas(Width=300.0,Height=300.0,Background=SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green))

addShapeAndLabel_at_coordinate "Tree Node 1" (100.0,50.0) canvas
addShapeAndLabel_at_coordinate "TreeNode 2" (150.0, 75.) canvas
shell.Content <- canvas

[<STAThread>] ignore <| (new Application()).Run shell
```

Answer (score 1):

To center text in given area (say, rectangle) you can simply wrap it by `Grid`. See example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898493/6131611). The grid can be positioned anywhere inside the canvas using `Left`, `Top`, `Width` and `Height` properties. The text will always stay in the center of grid.

This logic can be encapsulated in a custom FrameworkElement [like this](https://gist.github.com/PiN73/f930b23d91c493d65fe74b7b9faa7aaa).

To center text at point `(x, y)` you can calculate appropriate rectangle:

```
var text = new CenteredTextBlock
{
    Text = "Hello",
    Width = maxWidth,
    Height = maxHeight,
};
Canvas.SetLeft(text, x - maxWidth / 2);
Canvas.SetTop(text, y - maxHeight / 2);
Canvas.Children.Add(text);
```

where `(maxWidth, maxHeight)` is the maximum allowed size for text.

Answer (score 1):

I have extended [yetsta´s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784618/2003805) answer to include the possibility of horizontal and verical alignment:

```
  public class CanvasMover : DependencyObject
  {
    public enum Horizontal
    {
      Left,
      Center,
      Right
    }

    public enum Vertical
    {
      Top,
      Center,
      Bottom
    }

    public Point Position
    {
      get { return (Point)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
      set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static Horizontal GetHorizontalAlignment(DependencyObject obj)
    {
      return (Horizontal)obj.GetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty);
    }

    public static Point GetPosition(DependencyObject obj)
    {
      return (Point)obj.GetValue(PositionProperty);
    }

    public static Vertical GetVerticalAlignment(DependencyObject obj)
    {
      return (Vertical)obj.GetValue(VerticalAlignmentProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHorizontalAlignment(DependencyObject obj, Horizontal value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetPosition(DependencyObject obj, Point value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(PositionProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetVerticalAlignment(DependencyObject obj, Vertical value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(VerticalAlignmentProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalAlignment", typeof(Horizontal), typeof(CanvasMover),
          new PropertyMetadata(Horizontal.Center, DependencyPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Position", typeof(Point), typeof(CanvasMover),
          new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), DependencyPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VerticalAlignment", typeof(Vertical), typeof(CanvasMover),
          new PropertyMetadata(Vertical.Center, DependencyPropertyChanged));

    private static void DependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (dependencyObject is not FrameworkElement element)
      {
        return;
      }
      element.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
      element.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
      SetCanvasPosition(element);
    }

    private static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
      SetCanvasPosition(element);
    }

    private static void SetCanvasPosition(FrameworkElement element)
    {
      var position = CanvasMover.GetPosition(element);
      var horizontalAlignment = CanvasMover.GetHorizontalAlignment(element);
      var verticalAlignment = CanvasMover.GetVerticalAlignment(element);

      var left = position.X - (element.ActualWidth / 2);
      var top = position.Y - (element.ActualHeight / 2);

      if (horizontalAlignment == Horizontal.Left)
        left = position.X - element.ActualWidth;
      else if (horizontalAlignment == Horizontal.Right)
        left = position.X;

      if (verticalAlignment == Vertical.Top)
        top = position.Y - element.ActualHeight;
      else if (verticalAlignment == Vertical.Bottom)
        top = position.Y;

      element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
      element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, top);
    }
  }
```

The usage looks like this:

```
   <Label behaviors:CanvasMover.HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          behaviors:CanvasMover.Position="288,384"
          behaviors:CanvasMover.VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Content="Sample"
          Foreground="White" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant of [yetsta's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784618/3195477). One small flaw was that if the point value is set while the target element is NOT visible, then it's `ActualHeight` & `ActualWidth` may be zero. Thus the center point doesn't end up quite correct.

This can lead to some weird inconsistencies depending on the exact order of operations (sometimes visibility set before the point value... other times set after it ... etc.)

So this code includes catching of `IsVisibleChanged` to handle that.

```
public class CenterOnPoint
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterPointProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CenterPoint", typeof(Point), typeof(CenterOnPoint),
       new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnPointChanged));

    public static void SetCenterPoint(UIElement element, Point value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CenterPointProperty, value);
    }

    public static Point GetCenterPoint(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Point)element.GetValue(CenterPointProperty);
    }

    private static void OnPointChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)d;
        element.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
        element.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
        element.IsVisibleChanged -= OnIsVisibleChanged;
        element.IsVisibleChanged += OnIsVisibleChanged;
        var newPoint = (Point)e.NewValue;
        element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newPoint.X - (element.ActualWidth / 2));
        element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newPoint.Y - (element.ActualHeight / 2));
    }

    private static void OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var point = GetCenterPoint(element);
        element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, point.X - (element.ActualWidth / 2));
        element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, point.Y - (element.ActualHeight / 2));
    }

    private static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var newPoint = GetCenterPoint(element);
        element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newPoint.X - (e.NewSize.Width / 2));
        element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newPoint.Y - (e.NewSize.Height / 2));
    }
}
```